# Pulling hostnames from single line of text with regex

Tags: python, regex

I'm attempting to write a Python script pull all the Google Cloud Compute subnets from their DNS. More info about this here:

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/faq#where_can_i_find_short_product_name_ip_ranges

So far, I'm able pull the TXT record list of individual hostnames as a basestring with no problem.

```
import dns.resolver

# Set the resolver
my_resolver = dns.resolver.Resolver()
my_resolver.nameservers = ['8.8.8.8']

answer = my_resolver.query('_cloud-netblocks.googleusercontent.com', 'TXT')

for rdata in answer:
    for txt_string in rdata.strings:
        txt_record = txt_string
```

This leaves me with a string of

```
v=spf1 include:_cloud-netblocks1.googleusercontent.com include:_cloud-netblocks2.googleusercontent.com include:_cloud-netblocks3.googleusercontent.com include:_cloud-netblocks4.googleusercontent.com include:_cloud-netblocks5.googleusercontent.com ?all
```

What I would like to do is use re.match to extract the 5 hostnames from this initial response so I can do consecutive lookups and strip out the subnets then put them into an array. All my efforts with regex thus far haven't been so... great... I was wondering if anyone would provide some guidance? Thanks!

Edit:

Here is the full script for anyone else with a need to collect all of Google's Cloud IPs.

```
import dns.resolver, re

# Set the resolver
my_resolver = dns.resolver.Resolver()
my_resolver.nameservers = ['8.8.8.8']

answer = my_resolver.query('_cloud-netblocks.googleusercontent.com', 'TXT')

for rdata in answer:
    for txt_string in rdata.strings:
        txt_record = txt_string

# Extract hostnames into array
hostnames = [x.split(":")[1] for x in txt_record.split() if ":" in x]
total_subnets = []

for host in hostnames:
    answer = my_resolver.query(host, 'TXT')

    for rdata in answer:
        for txt_string in rdata.strings:
            txt_record = txt_string

    ip4_subnets = re.findall(r'ip4:(\S+)', txt_record)
    ip6_subnets = re.findall(r'ip6:(\S+)', txt_record)

    for subnet in ip4_subnets:
        total_subnets.append(subnet)

    for subnet in ip6_subnets:
        total_subnets.append(subnet)

print total_subnets
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to use a regex for this, use `split` twice and comprehension:

```
s = "v=spf1 include:_cloud-netblocks1.googleusercontent.com include:_cloud-netblocks2.googleusercontent.com include:_cloud-netblocks3.googleusercontent.com include:_cloud-netblocks4.googleusercontent.com include:_cloud-netblocks5.googleusercontent.com ?all"
print([x.split(":")[1] for x in s.split() if ":" in x])
# => ['_cloud-netblocks1.googleusercontent.com', 
#     '_cloud-netblocks2.googleusercontent.com',
#     '_cloud-netblocks3.googleusercontent.com',
#     '_cloud-netblocks4.googleusercontent.com',
#     '_cloud-netblocks5.googleusercontent.com']
```

See the [demo here](http://ideone.com/nYGCGs)

**Details**:

- `s.split()` - splits with spaces
- `if ":" in x` - only gets those entries with a `:` inside
- `x.split(":")[1]` - splits the above entries with `:` and gets the second chunk

Certainly, if you wish, you can use a regex:

```
include:(\S+)
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/lV1rC3/1).

This will match `include:` and will capture 1+ non-whitespace symbols into Group 1. `re.findall` will fetch you the list (`re.findall(r'include:(\S+)', s)`).

Comment: Excellent! Worked great! Thanks so much!